# IndexError: list index out of range, counting empty cells in dataset

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to this so please forgive my ignorance. I've imported a data set .csv and I'm simply trying to 'count' the empty fields in a specific row.

As I said, my data is a .csv format I understand the basic premise that row count starts at 0 (not 1), so I'm struggling to understand why I'm getting this error. I've used the same code on a similar dataset and didn't have this issue.

[screenshot of the .csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS3vX.png)

```
# How many many records are there in the record
filehandle = 
open("Underground_Storage_Tank_UST_Records_Residential.csv", "r")
# r = read /
header = True
num_rows = 0

num_missing_tank_size = 0

for line in filehandle:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split(',')

    if header:
        header = False
        continue

    num_rows += 1

    if columns[3] == '':
        num_missing_tank_size += 1

print("Total Records: \n")
print(num_rows)

print("Records missing tank SIZE: ")
print(num_missing_tank_size)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oiltank_count.py", line 23, in <module>
    if columns[3] == '':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a line in your file?

Comment: For sure : Address Permit Number Date Issued Tank Size Tank Age Tank Content Date Decommissioned Type Decommissioned Fill Material Zip Code
3102 NE 55 ST - TANK #3 3-117136 5/23/19    5/24/19   98105

Comment: I added a link an image of the file in the original post—which will probably give you a better understanding of how it's laid out and indexed.

Comment: Please include data as text, not as a screenshot. Also, why don't you use module `csv`?

Comment: Like I mentioned, I'm very much a beginner in this space. Not using module csv because my teacher didn't use it in class. That said, I tried using import csv in my code (as referenced in this link) and it didn't really help. https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/csv/using-the-csv-module-in-python